# Subtracting of a SUM?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I was wondering if I could perform this algebraic use, Here is the ones I am trying to perform with.

```
JCCM.BilledAmt + JCCM.udGEACrev As REVENUE_2,
(JCCM.udGEACrev + JCCM.BilledAmt) - JCCP.ActualCost As BilledCostDifference,
```

I tried adding REVENUE_2 between the brackets but the Report Builder does not take it as a column

Comment: why these much tags?

Comment: Does ReportBuilder work with mySQL?

Comment: You can't use a column alias defined at the same "level".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Add a calculated field to your dataset:
   -Right click dataset -> `Add Calculated Field`
2. Enter the following values in the dialog that pops up:
   -`Field name`: `REVENUE_2`
   -`Field source`: `Fields!JCCM.BilledAmt.Value + Fields!JCCM.udGEACrev.Value`
3. Add another calculated field with the following values:
   -`Field name`: `BilledCostDifference`
   -`Field source`: `Fields!REVENUE_2.Value - Fields!JCCP.ActualCost.Value`
4. Drag the second calculated field to your report.

**NOTE:**
SSRS will not recognize the first calculated field you added unless you hit OK. So add the first calculated field, hit OK, add the second calculated field.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about the calculated fields,